# Join operation on parent child in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have company and employee information.
I was successfully able to index them as parent and children document.
has_children query works fine , but then i need both matching parent and children.
Is this possible in Elasticsearch

Comment: Kindly add some more Content to your Question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking to join the results and give both parent and children documents.
From Elasticsearch version 1.5.0 , they have introduced a feature called [inner hits](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-request-inner-hits.html) which can achieve it.